# remove-item -force not working on download

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

so i had writen this script that will clear out the files in thedownload but it doesn't work

```
$DaysToDelete = 1
```

download

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\users\*\Downloads\*"-Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Where-Object { ($_.CreationTime -lt $(Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysToDelete))} | 
remove-item -force -Verbose -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what _doesn't work_ means? Are you getting an error? Does the running user have access to those files? You have `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` which would hide all your errors. Remove that for testing.

Comment: iknow but it doesn't come up with any errors 
and all the files is still in the download folders when i running the script and the user have acces to it and have permissions

Comment: If you ran just this in console `Get-ChildItem "C:\users\*\Downloads\*"-Recurse -Force` does it return anything? If it returned nothing then the rest of the code would not be executed. I get access denied if not run from an admin console.

Comment: i only got acces denied when i used $Error and after i runned it in administrator worked but i getting acces denied when i trying to remove from other users folders are there any way to allow it to do that? and always run that script in administrator mode

Answer (score 1):

This code is valid in what it is supposed to do. If there are any errors with file access or anything else, you can inspect them via `$Error` 
[automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)

Comment: okay i tryed with $Error and it said acces denied and it referating to `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\ `and then i tryed to do it for temp then i got  `UnauthorizedAccessException` when it tryed to remove the file

Comment: For the script in the OP I can't see a way it could reach a different folder `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download` Please post your entire console output so it includes the dcript and the error. As I have mentioned, it is most probably access rights on the filesystem. To eliminate this - assign your current user full permissions to one of the folders and test your script against it. I have run it on my system and it behaved as expected.